# In console error showing ignore attempt to cancel a touchend

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I design on form for user registration in ionic app, run in debug mode on phone and fill form and when I'm submitting form application not responding anything else and when I'm checking it on console error is showing like

> "Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for
>   example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted."

```html
<ion-view view-title="Sign Up" class="login-main">
    <ion-header-bar>
        <h1 class="title">Sign Up</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="login-both-fields">

                <div class="list">
                    <form class="padding" id="signup-form" ng-submit="signup(signupForm.$valid)" name="signupForm" novalidate>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label login-input-icon"><i class="ion-person"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Name*" name="m_name" ng-model="mSignupData.m_name" required>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.m_name.$error.required" class="popup-validation-signup">
                                Please enter name
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label login-input-icon"><i class="ion-person"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Surename*" name="m_surename" ng-model="mSignupData.m_surename" required>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.m_surename.$error.required" class="popup-validation-signup">
                        Please enter surename
                    </span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label login-input-icon"><i class="ion-ios-location"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Address*" name="m_address" ng-model="mSignupData.m_address" required>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.m_address.$error.required" class="popup-validation-signup">Please enter address</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label login-input-icon"><i class="ion-calendar"></i></span>
                            <input type="date" placeholder="Date Of Birth*" name="m_dob" ng-model="mSignupData.m_dob" required>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.m_dob.$error.required" class="popup-validation-signup">Please enter DOB</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label login-input-icon"><i class="ion-iphone"></i></span>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="m_mobno" ng-model="mSignupData.m_mobno" required> 
                            <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.m_mobno.$error.required" class="popup-validation-signup">Please enter mobile no</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label login-input-icon"><i class="ion-ios-email"></i></span>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" name="m_email" ng-model="mSignupData.m_email" required>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.m_email.$error.required" class="popup-validation-signup">Please enter emailid</span>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.m_email.$error.email" class="popup-validation-signup">Please enter valid emailid</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label login-input-icon"><i class="ion-person"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="User Name*" name="m_username" ng-model="mSignupData.m_username" required>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.m_username.$error.required" class="popup-validation-signup">Please enter username</span>
                        </label> 
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label login-input-icon"><i class="ion-locked"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password*" name="m_pwd" ng-model="mSignupData.m_pwd" ng-minlength="8" required>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.m_pwd.$error.required" class="popup-validation-signup">Please enter password</span>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && loginForm.m_pwd.$error.minlength" class="validation-login popup-forvalidation correct-password-login-error">Password should be min 8 character.</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="term-line-signup">
                            <input id="terms" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" ng-model="mSignupData.vehicle" required> <label for="terms" class="lable-readinfo">By Accept</label>  <a href="javascript:;" class="links-for-terms-page">terms& conditions.</a>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.vehicle.$error.required" class="popup-validation-signup please-confirm-condtion">Please accept terms&condition</span>
                            
                        </div>
                       
                        <button type="submit" ng-click="submitted = true" class="button button-block button-positive button-energized client-btn">Register</button>
                        <a class="button button-block button-positive  Normal-btn" href="#/mLogin">Signin</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `return true` from touchend and everything will work fine.

Do like this :

```
var scroll=false;

//while moving
$("body").on("touchmove", function(){
      scroll = true;
});

//at the end of touch
$("body").on("touchend", function(){
      if (scroll)
          return;

      // wasn't a drag, just a tap
      // more code here
});

//when touch starts
$("body").on("touchstart", function(){
    scroll = false;
});
```